# hide-windowsupdate Permission Issue

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-update

I am trying to hide a windows update that's causing havoc on our systems, but something is causing the app to get blocked, when running over the network. We are on an AD domain and I'm running this command as an administrator on the machine. When I run the command:

```
hide-windowsupdate -debug -microsoftupdate -computername COMPUTER -KBArticleID "KB5000808"
```

I get this...

```
hide-windowsupdate : COMPUTER: You don't have permission to perform this task.
At line:1 char:1
+ hide-windowsupdate -verbose -microsoftupdate  -computername COMPUTER
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-WindowsUpdate], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80240044,PSWindowsUpdate.GetWindowsUpdate
```

but I'm on the administrators group, running as an administrator and the command works perfectly fine, if performed locally.

Here is an article about the module.
https://www.parallels.com/blogs/ras/powershell-windows-update/

Comment: Are these machines connected to an Active Directory domain?  It appears you are not providing a username and password, that I would logically assume, would be required since by default the lowest permission of a user is used.  Since you are running this command remotely that would explain the error message.  I assume you are running that command locally since you indicate it works locally.  What exactly is `hide-windowsupdate`?  Where can I read about it so I can answer your question?

Comment: Do you use a WSUS Server? If you deny the update there it also won't get installed by your machines

Comment: The -microsoftupdate flag makes the command look for a microsoft server, rather than a WSUS server.